# Punctuation in LaTeX formulas

Tags: latex, punctuation

It seems to be common practice, when writing mathematics, to add punctuation to displayed formulas.

Is there any trick to avoid putting the punctuation mark inside the formula?

I want to avoid

```
Consider the function
\[ \sin(x).\]
```

I'd rather have something like:

```
Consider the function
\[ \sin(x)\].
```

But of course the full stop is displayed below the formula.

Is there a clever way to separate formulas and punctuation in LaTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the [breqn package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/breqn.html) (compatible with amsmath) and have this behaviour inbuilt with its dmath environment:

```
Consider the function
\begin{dmath}\sin(x)\end{dmath}.
```

Will output the same as `\[\sin(x).\]`, i.e., as if the dot was inside the expression.

As a bonus, you'll also get automatic line-breaking in your math equation.

Comment: Interesting package but I can't see the relation with the original question... `breqn` seems to be a package for breaking long equations; the OP was about punctuation in displayed equation.

Comment: @Olivier: Did I miss something in my explanation? the OP asked for `\[\sin(x)\].` to pull the period inside the display math, and that's *exactly* what my example above does.

Comment: Oh! You are right. This is brilliant! It's just that the docs for `breqn` are so messy that I could not find it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

```
\catcode`\@=11 
\let\seveendformula\]
\def\]{\@ifnextchar.\PointAndEndFormula\seveendformula}
\def \PointAndEndFormula #1{.\seveendformula}
\catcode`\@=12
```

**Add**

More complex solution works with `.,?!;:` :

```
\catcode`\@=11 
\def\addtopunct#1{\expandafter\let\csname punct@\meaning#1\endcsname\let}
\addtopunct{.}    \addtopunct{,}    \addtopunct{?}
\addtopunct{!}    \addtopunct{;}    \addtopunct{:}

\let\seveendformula\]
\def\PunctAndEndFormula #1{#1\seveendformula}
\def\]{\futurelet\punctlet\checkpunct@i}
\def\checkpunct@i{\expandafter\ifx\csname punct@\meaning\punctlet\endcsname\let  
       \expandafter\PunctAndEndFormula 
       \else \expandafter\seveendformula\fi}
\catcode`\@=12
```

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I thought of this, but an issue is that there is quite a bit of possible punctuation that you might want to follow a displaymath: probably not '!' or ':', but besides '.' each of ',', ';' and '?' are quite common.  +1 for answering the question without petty qualms.

Comment: Very stylish.  I don't think I could have written this new code: this is pretty deep stuff.

Comment: This is *brilliant*! It is so useful that it should maybe be put together as a LaTeX package?

Comment: Here is an improvement: I will put the punctuation after the displayed equations, use your trick, and if I change my mind it is easy to disable the display of the punctuation by replacing your `\def\PunctAndEndFormula #1{#1\seveendformula}` by `\def\PunctAndEndFormula #1{\seveendformula}`. Magic! Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please explain what this code does / how it's supposed to be used?

Answer (score 9):

There's also the issue of which *font* the punctuation should be in. You won't see a problem until you try a different math font such as Euler. Then commas and periods are clearly different in text mode and in math mode. I've written text-mode punctuation in displayed formulas as `\mbox{,}` or lazily as `\mbox,` just before `$$`.

Comment: \text, is more highlevel.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the punctuation inside a display environment is the usual way.  The problem is that when Latex processes the `\]`, it ends the mathbox, so anything following will be part of a new vertical box.

You could try something like:

```
\hbox{\[My formula\]}.
```

This is not tested, and probably has spacing issues, but if you are interested in this kind of solution, I could try and get something working.

FWIW, you might be interested in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6675/periods-and-commas-in-mathematical-writing

Comment: Thanks for the link! Reading the answers there, I am relieved to see that I am not the only one to think that punctuation should not be part of the formulas.